# How can I execute bash command in a function like as map?

Tags: vimscript

I have a tricky problem and don't know how to solve it. I use `map` to declare a shortcut key for the gradle test below:

```
map <C-S-F10> <Esc>:wa<CR>:let last_test = expand("%")<CR><S-F10>
map <S-F10> <Esc>:wa<CR>:call OpenWindow('tests')<CR>:%d<CR>:call RunTests(last_test)<CR>

fun! RunTests(...)
  if(a:0 == 0)
    silent .!./gradlew test
  else
    execute "silent" ".!./gradlew test --tests '*".a:1."'"
  endif
endfun

fun! OpenWindow(bufname)
  let winid = bufwinid(a:bufname)
  if(winid != -1) "buff window is not closed
    call win_gotoid(winid)
    return
  endif

  let absent = ! bufexists(a:bufname)
  execute "new ".a:bufname
  "move window to bottom
  let n = winnr('$') - winnr()
  execute n.'wincmd r'

  if(absent) "set options & map for new buffer
    set bufhidden=hide buftype=nofile nobuflisted noswapfile
    map <buffer> q <Esc>:q<CR>
  endif

endfun
```

When I press `<C-S-F10>` this behavior is what I want:

- First, if the tests buffer does not exist, then create a new buffer named tests, otherwise open/focus the window for the existing tests buffer.
- Next, clear the last test result in tests buffer by `%d`
- Finally, execute `RunTests` and fill the result of `!./gradlew test` into `tests` buffer.

But when I went to refactor the mapping as below, the behavior is not what I want. All of the steps above will not be done until the bash script is done. How can I make my `OpenRunTests` execute the behavior like the mapping?

```
map <C-F10> <Esc>:wa<CR>:silent OpenWinAndRunTests()<CR>

fun! OpenWinAndRunTests()
  call OpenWindow("tests")
  %d  "clear buffer is not done until the shell command finished, how can I fix it?
  call RunTests(g:last_test)
endfun
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a full range with you filter command.

```
%!./gradlew test
```

However I have some other thoughts:

- You may want to look into use `:make` and the quickfix list ([gradle compiler plugin](https://github.com/mearns/vim-gradle))
- You could `:bwipe` the buffer and opening a new one
- I would recommend supplying a mode with your `map`'s. e.g. `nmap` (Use `noremap` if possible)
- May want to use `wincmd J` instead of rotating the window down

Personally I would recommend you look into `:make` and the quickfix list. Using `:make` allows for you to collect your errors up into a list known as the quickfix list. Open the quickfix list in a window via `:copen`. Using the quickfix you can navigate between the errors in your files, so you are jumping right to where the compiler/linter/test runner says the error is (handy right?).

For more help see:

```
:h :range
:h :make
:h quickfix
:h :compiler
:h 'errorformat'
:h 'makeprg'
:h :copen
:h :wincmd
:h CTRL-W_J
:h :bw
```

Comment: Hi, I want to show it in vim console, because I can use vim features. e.g: search, copy and .etc. and it is quickly return to my workshop when I press down `q`. and then I can write my own syntax for my tests to highlight the test result.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is whenever execute bash command will prevent vim redrawing screen. Actually, it wasn't blocked until the bash command done. So I only need to redraw the screen before execute bash. for example:

```
"    v--- redraw the screen before run `./gradlew test`
%d | redraw | silent .!./gradlew test
```

The advantage of clear buffer before execute hash is that I can know exactly that the bash whether is done, since I only can see a blank buffer view when the bash is in progress.